# remove ^M characters from file using sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have this line inside a file:

```
ULNET-PA,client_sgcib,broker_keplersecurities
,KEPLER
```

I try to get rid of that ^M (carriage return) character so I used:

```
sed 's/^M//g'
```

However this does remove everything after ^M:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# vi test
ULNET-PA,client_sgcib,broker_keplersecurities^M,KEPLER

[root@localhost tmp]# sed 's/^M//g' test
ULNET-PA,client_sgcib,broker_keplersecurities
```

What I want to obtain is:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# vi test
ULNET-PA,client_sgcib,broker_keplersecurities,KEPLER
```

Comment: Why not use `\n` or `\r\n` in your expression?

Comment: @fedorqui It's not `^` and `M` literally, it's `^M`, IIRC, called a `control character`.

Comment: Use $ tr -d '\015' <file1 >file2; mv file2 file1

Comment: Simply way is, using 'dos2unix <fileName>'

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use `tr`:

```
tr -d '^M' < inputfile
```

(Note that the `^M` character can be input using <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>)

---

EDIT: As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406418/remove-m-characters-from-file-using-sed/19406498?noredirect=1#comment28766761_19406498) by [Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman), if you're using `bash`, you could also say:

```
tr -d $'\r' < inputfile
```

Comment: +1 for the simplest solution.  Also note that you can use octal codes in tr, like `tr -d '\012'` to remove newlines for example.  And you can use `od -bc inputfile` to browse what codes mean what and are where in a file.

Comment: @twalberg I gues `dos2unix` would remove CR only from the end of line.  The example in the question doesn't make it evident whether it's present only at the end of line.

Comment: @devnull I guess maybe it's not universal, but my `dos2unix` has several different options for controlling conversion mode that may be appropriate (in particular the ones for dealing with Mac files, that seem to like to use `^M` line endings). It may not be a perfect solution for the OPs current question, but it's a good thing to know about, hence the "see also...".

Comment: If you're using bash, you can write `tr -d $'\r'`

Comment: @twalberg => Yes, dos2unix can be made to do this on Mac, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406418/remove-m-characters-from-file-using-sed/31517990#31517990), below.

Comment: @glennjackman May I know what does the dollar sign "$" do there? I did some search, but wasn't able to figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: that is [bash ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Answer (score 24):

still the same line:

```
sed -i 's/^M//g' file
```

when you type the command, for `^M` you type <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>

actually if you have already opened the file in vim, you can just in vim do:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

same,  `^M` you type `Ctrl-V Ctrl-M`

Comment: Just hold Ctrl and press V then M

Comment: The OP said he wanted a solution using `sed`.

Comment: Use $ tr -d '\015' <file1 >file2;  mv file2 file1

Comment: This worked, please check this link for more variations: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-remove-m-and-line-feeds-under-unix-linux-bsd-appleosx/

Answer (score 12):

You can simply use dos2unix which is available in most Unix/Linux systems. However I found the following sed command to be better as it removed ^M where dos2unix couldn't:

```
sed 's/\r//g' < input.txt >  output.txt
```

Hope that helps.

Note: ^M is actually carriage return character which is represented in code as \r
What dos2unix does is most likely equivalent to:

```
sed 's/\r\n/\n/g' < input.txt >  output.txt
```

It doesn't remove \r when it is not immediately followed by \n and replaces both with just \n. This fails with certain types of files like one I just tested with.

Comment: nice explanation!! Thnks!!

Comment: Indeed, nice explanation. Your approach does seem to work on any instance I've tested where dos2unix failed.

Answer (score 7):

```
alias dos2unix="sed -i -e 's/'\"\$(printf '\015')\"'//g' "
```

Usage:

```
dos2unix file
```

Comment: how can you use this command in a shell script, without alias?  kept getting sed to complain about some syntax....like solution with \015 char vs ^M

Comment: @bjm88 I found this somewhere: `sed 's,'$'\015'',,'`

Answer (score 3):

If Perl is an option:

`perl -i -pe 's/\r\n$/\n/g' file`

`-i` makes a .bak version of the input file
`\r` = carriage return
`\n` = linefeed
`$` = end of line
`s/foo/bar/g` = globally substitute "foo" with "bar"

Comment: how do i use the same in perl script. `test.pl`

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
open IN, "<", shift;
open OUT, ">", shift;
while ( <IN> ) {
    s/\r\n$/\n/g;
    print OUT;
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);

Comment: test.pl infile outfile

Comment: Note that the test.pl solution in the comments will NOT create a backup file.  Instead, it will write a separate file.

Answer (score 3):

This is the better way to achieve

```
tr -d '\015' < inputfile_name > outputfile_name
```

Later rename the file to original file name.

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
sub(/\r/,"")
```

If it is in the end of record, `sub(/\r/,"",$NF)` should suffice. No need to scan the whole record.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg) (see [accepted answer comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406418/remove-m-characters-from-file-using-sed/19406498#19406498), above), dos2unix on Mac OSX covers this, quoting `man dos2unix`:

> To run in Mac mode use the command-line option "-c mac" or use the
>   commands "mac2unix" or "unix2mac"

I settled on 'mac2unix', which got rid of my less-cmd-visible '^M' entries, introduced by an Apple 'Messages' transfer of a bash script between 2 Yosemite (OSX 10.10) Macs!

I installed 'dos2unix', trivially, on Mac OSX using the popular [Home**brew**](http://brew.sh) package installer, I highly recommend it and it's companion command, [Cask](http://caskroom.io).

Answer (score 1):

This is clean and simple and it works:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' file
```

where `\r` of course is the equivalent for `^M`.

Comment: Not all `sed` variants recognize the escape `\r`. In original Unix, it would simply mean a regular `r` character with an unnecessary escape which is simply ignored. This is still the behavior on BSD / macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the following command:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r$//' input.file
```

I verified this as valid in Mac OSX Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

remove any `\r` :

> ```
> nawk 'NF+=OFS=_' FS='\r'
> gawk   3  ORS=   RS='\r'
> ```

remove end of line `\r` :

> ```
> mawk2 8 RS='\r?\n'
> mawk -F'\r$' NF=1
> ```