# git diff - ^M characters

Tags: git

I used to get `warnings` about `LF will be replaced by CRLF` when doing a `git commit`.

I played around with `autocrlf` but setting it to `true` or `false` both caused problems. In the end, after this comment ([LF will be replaced by CRLF in git - What is that and is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important/9094476#9094476)) by @Drew Noakes, I just unset it and that fixed the `warnings`.

However, now, when I run `git diff` I get output like this:

```
-       original line;
+       new line;^M
```

What's going on and is there any way of getting rid of these pesky `^M`s once and for all?

If it helps, this is my own repo (i.e. I have complete control over the code base) and I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Do you have `.gitattributes` files with `core.eol` directive in it?

Comment: @VonC I don't but I do have a .gitattributes file with `*.pbxproj -crlf -diff -merge` in  it. I assume that's got nothing to do with the problem as it's only applying this to pbxproj files.

Answer (score 1):

Try running [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) or a similar program on the tex file.

Comment: Broken link. Here's a good one: [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)

Comment: Warning: this could change every line in your git file.

Answer (score 0):

To remove them, you can execute something like this from your shell:

```
$ find -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/^M//g' {} +
```

... where you need to insert `^M` using [Ctrl+V] [Ctrl+M] (see here for more options [remove ^M characters from file using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406418/remove-m-characters-from-file-using-sed)). Since you're on a Mac, they shouldn't come back after that, but I admit I'm not entirely sure about git not putting them back.