# sed command working inline but not inside bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, newline, carriage-return

I have this inline sed command:

```
sed -e 's/^M/\'$'\n/g' filename.txt
```

which is working inline, but not inside a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/^M/\'$'\n/g' $1
```

Removing \'$' from the code doesn't solve the problem (replaces ^M with just an "n").

Cheers, Andrea

Comment: Does your real `path/to/filename.txt` contain any spaces? If so, your problem should be resolved by writing `"$1"` instead of just `$1`.

Comment: no it doesn't, but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

In `#!/bin/bash` you need to use `$'\r'` instead of `^M`

You can use the `tr` (tr*anslate*) command

```
#!/bin/bash
tr -d $'\r' < $1
```

See: [remove ^M characters from file using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406418/remove-m-characters-from-file-using-sed) for a solution for removing carriage return

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually what I needed was: `tr $'\r' $'\n' < $1`