# How to remove files whose names contain Ctrl-M?

Tags: shell, unix, special-characters

In the (C-)shell, how can I remove all files whose filenames contain `Ctrl-M`? (Don't ask me how I made these!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove ^M characters from file using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406418/remove-m-characters-from-file-using-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is described as "C-)shell". Not clear if OP can use different shell.

**Using bash**

Using ctrl-v to escape the ctrl-M

```
rm -i *<ctrl-v><ctrl-m>*
```

**For tcsh**

On most systems, csh is supported by tcsh. Depending on you build of tcsh, might be possible to Carriage Return - Ctrl-M, using the sequence . Using  will result in new line. Most likely, this is the result of terminal setting (`stty`, probably inlcr), which can map between new lines and carriage return.

If this work, then you can remove those files using

```
rm -i *<ctrl-v><ctrl-j>*
```

Comment: The bash solution worked. For (t)csh, one must include in quotes: `rm -i "*<ctrl-v><ctrl-j>*"` or `rm -i *"<ctrl-v><ctrl-j>"*`. Thanks a lot!