How to add headers to a CSV file which already has some headers in it
My requirement it to add the new headers to an existing CSV file which already has some headers in the fist line. I need to add the new headers at the end of the existing headers. The value of the new headers will be empty; I just need to create the header.
For e.g. below is my CSV file
Cust_Name,Cust_ADD
A1,CBD
A2,CBE
A3,CBE

I need to add headers "salary,age" at the end of the CSV file.
I tried this code
sed -i "1s|\$|,$new_headers|" input.csv

It is giving me output like below
Cust_Name,Cust_ADD
,Salary,age
A1,CBD
A2,CBE
A3,CBE

The new headers are appearing on the second line.
Expected Output
Cust_Name,Cust_ADD,salary,age
A1,CBD,,
A2,CBE,,
A3,CBE,,


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -i '1s/$/,salary,age/;1!s//,,/' file

On the first line append ,salary,age.
On all other lines append ,,
N.B. The second substitute command because it is empty uses the previous regex but provides a new value to be appended i.e. s//,,/.

With any awk
% awk '{NR == 1 ? $0=$0",salary,age" : $0=$0",,"}1' file.csv
Cust_Name,Cust_ADD,salary,age
A1,CBD,,
A2,CBE,,
A3,CBE,,

Data
% cat file.csv
Cust_Name,Cust_ADD
A1,CBD
A2,CBE
A3,CBE


I am still getting the new headers in the second line awk '{NR == 1 ? $0=$0",salary,age" : $0=$0",,"}1' input.csv > input.csv

You should not redirect to the same file. Use a temporary file, e.g. awk '{NR == 1 ? $0=$0",salary,age" : $0=$0",,"}1' input.csv > input_mod.csv && mv input_mod.csv input.csv 

I tried it awk '{NR == 1 ? $0=$0",salary,age" : $0=$0",,"}1' input.csv > temp.csv && mv temp.csv input.csv the new headers are coming in second line

Did you try it with the posted data? Does it work there? How does input.csv look like? Is there a windows newline at the end of the first line? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406418/remove-m-characters-from-file-using-sed

thats correct there is new line at the end of the first line after removing it using sed -i '1s/\r$//' input.csv am able to create the headers in the first line, but there is empty line created at the end of each line

If there is additional data in the result it's probably already present in the source input.csv. Turn on show whitespace or similar in your favourite editor and check the file.

able to fix it by using awk 'NR == 1 { $0 = $0 ",Salary,age"}1' input.csv > temp.csv && mv temp.csv input.csv

You might have DOS line endings, see Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?.
Once that's fixed if necessary then using any awk:
$ awk '{print $0 (NR>1 ? ",," : ",salary,age")}' file
Cust_Name,Cust_ADD,salary,age
A1,CBD,,
A2,CBE,,
A3,CBE,,

For more info on manipulating CSVs with awk see What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?.

Ye old first introduction to dos2unix and unix2dos is always a good tip. Good catch.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.csv content be
Cust_Name,Cust_ADD
A1,CBD
A2,CBE
A3,CBE

then
awk -v headers="salary,age" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==1{$0=$0 "," headers;fnum=NF}{NF=fnum;print}' file.csv

gives output
Cust_Name,Cust_ADD,salary,age
A1,CBD,,
A2,CBE,,
A3,CBE,,

Explanation: I ram headers using -v switch (so if you have headers in shell variable named headers you might do headers="$headers") and inform GNU AWK that comma is both field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS), in 1st line I add comma and headers to line and save number of fields (NF) to fnum variable. For each variable I set number of fields to fnum to make GNU AWK add suitable number of empty fields and print line.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Setting new_headers=salary,age and running your sed command on the input you provide does not produce the output you provide. So, it is almost certainly the case that something you haven't shown is causing your problem with the oddly-placed newline.
Check the contents of both the input file and the variable. Use something that lets you see all characters. For example:
sed -n "=;l;s|\$|,$new_headers|;l;q" input.csv


= - print line number
l - print original line in "visually unambiguous" form
s/// - perform substitution
l - print modified line in "visually unambiguous" form
q - quit (to prove only first line is processed)

